# waiting between each execution in my selenium webdriver code?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Does anyone have an idea on how I can wait between these actions in my selenium code because when I am running it I am getting different results every time because the browser runs at different speeds each time. Is there a way so that between each moveByOffSet I can make it wait for a few seconds?

```
 Actions builder2 = new Actions(driver);
    Action moveByOffset = builder2.moveByOffset(100, 200)
            .click()
            .moveByOffset(-150, 0)
            .click()
            .moveByOffset(0, -150)
            .click()
            .moveByOffset(150, 0)
            .click()
            .moveByOffset(0, 150)
            .contextClick()              
            .build();
    moveByOffset.perform();
```

Comment: Is there anything you are waiting for, or why do you need waiting? Selenium has a way to wait for element to appear etc. Waiting for a fixed time is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

You could inherit from Actions class and override click() method including sleep inside its body.

```java
public class MyActions extends Actions {

    public MyActions(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    @Override
    public Actions click() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //do something
        }
        return super.click();
    }
}
```

and then simply use new class in your tests.

```
Actions actions = new MyActions(driver);
```

Please have in mind that putting sleep calls in test code is not a good practice. Consider using functionality provided by WebDriverWait class.

Comment: I have tried using wait for example: 

.click()
.moveByOffset(-150, 0)
.wait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

Something like that